# Math.round returns an integer, but not every time

Tags: javascript, rounding

I have the following code for showing how long ago a comment was made:

```
var timestamp = (new Date().getTime())/1000;
var comment_time = timestamp - responses[i]['time'];
var time_string = '';
if(comment_time < 60)
    time_string = Math.round(comment_time)+"s ago";
else if(comment_time < 3600)
    time_string = Math.round(comment_time/60)+"m ago";
else if(comment_time < 86400)
    time_string = Math.round(comment_time/3600)+"h ago";
else
    time_string = Math.round(comment_time/86400)+"d ago";
```

This works just fine, unless the comment is less than a minute old. When that happens, no rounding occurs at all. It looks like I'm getting a consistent 15 significant digits if the comment is less than one minute old. Once it gets older than one minute, everything works fine. What can be done about this?

Comment: seems fine to me http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6m5D8/1/

Comment: Is this in a particular browser? I just tried to create a similar issue using Firebug's console however it is rounding correctly for me.

Comment: Also I will suggest the [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) library

Comment: Try setting up a jsfiddle with real data, so we can understand what's wrong

Comment: Per Arun's jsFiddle, the logic works just fine so your problem has to be something related to the data in `responses[i]['time']`.  That's where you should look and there's not much we can do here without more information about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `parseInt()` with fractional parts

```
time_string = parseInt(Math.round(comment_time/60))+"m ago";
```

also go get it in there with jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6m5D8/1/